# Aggregate all my posts on all my forums

Tags: webapp-rec

I remember a few years ago there was a site which implemented this badly. What I'm looking for is a way to track threads that I post in regardless of what forum I post them in. Also useful would be the ability to flag a thread, following it, but independent of going there to check.

Seems natural that this would exist. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

**Tracking Replies**

An easy option would be to have a dedicated email account you use to register on forums and turn on the notification option (or subscribe to threads you post in individually) for each one.

**Remembering posts**

You could bookmark each one using a social bookmarking service such as [delicious](http://delicious.com/).

---

Given the wide veriety of software powering forums, workarounds such as those would probably be more effective than a dedicated app.